# Error: When I try to install any package

Tags: 12.04, software-center

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. I am in  great trouble when I tried to install firefox browser. However firefox installation is broken on my system. After this when I go to UBUNTU SOFTWARE CENTER it showing me this message every time and fail to install any other package.

UBUNTU SOFTWARE CENTER :

Item cannot be installed or removed until the package catalog is repaired.

When I try to install anything from terminal I always get this below message:

Error1 :

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 firefox-globalmenu : Depends: firefox (= 19.0~b5+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1~mfn1)

Please tell how I can repair it. Looking for your guidance.

==========================================================================

```
        yes I just seen it and tried this  command: apt-get -f install
```

E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

```
            PLEASE SEE FROM HERE WHAT MESSAGE I HAVE :
            deepak@deepak-laptop:/$ sudo apt-get -f install
            Reading package lists... Done
            Building dependency tree       
             Reading state information... Done
             Correcting dependencies... Done
            The following extra packages will be installed:
             firefox firefox-globalmenu
             Suggested packages:
             latex-xft-fonts firefox-gnome-support
           The following NEW packages will be installed:
            firefox
           The following packages will be upgraded:
           firefox-globa lmenu
          1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 220 not upgraded.
           1 not fully installed or removed.
          Need to get 0 B/24.8 MB of archives.
         After this operation, 51.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
         Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
         (Reading database ... 354341 files and directories currently installed.)
         Unpacking firefox (from  .../firefox_19.0~b6+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1~mfn1_i386.deb) ...
             dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives /firefox_19.0~b6+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1~mfn1_i386.deb (--unpack):
             trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/firefox/plugins', which is also in package acroread 9.5.1-1precise1
            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Processing triggers for man-db ...
                    Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
                   Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
                 Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
            Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
            Errors were encountered while processing:
                 /var/cache/apt/archives  /firefox_19.0~b6+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1~mfn1_i386.deb
                E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

==========================================================================

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `sudo apt-get install -f` in the terminal. This attempts to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.

Comment: I tried above command . It appeared to work but at last moment I have some error. I also pasted output of this command along with question text. Please give a look on question where I edited at last.

Comment: This is the error :Errors were encountered while processing:
                 /var/cache/apt/archives  /firefox_19.0~b6+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1~mfn1_i386.deb
                E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run uninstall `acroread 9.5.1-1precise1` from your system.That is probably creating problems.

Simply try uninstalling acroread using `sudo apt-get remove acroread`
After that, try installing firefox again. In my opinion it should go through after that.

Answer (score 0):

Force dpkg to overwrite files:

```
sudo dpkg --force-overwrite -i /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_19.0~b6+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1~mfn1_i386.deb
```

Then, run this command to fix remaining unconfigured packages:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Anyways, as someone else stated, the culprit here is probably the `acroread` package. If you continue to see these messages, just uninstall `acroread` from your system.